# Is a group in which $a^3 = 1$ for all $a \in G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Suppose that $G$ is a group in which $a^3 =1$ for all $a \in G$. Is $G$ abelian?

I tried to play around with algebraic expressions. I found e.g. $(ab)^2 = b^2 a^2$ for all $a,b$. I don't know what to do.

I also can't find a counterexample.

Thanks for help

Comment: Think about matrix groups that might make it non abelian, think about what the field entries might be in to make sure $a^3=1$.

Comment: Consider the (multiplicative) group of matrices of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&a&b\\
0&1&c\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: @user386627 : $(12)^3 = (12)$.

Answer (score 7):

Nope, the simples example is problably the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p) over $\mathbb{F}_3$, which has order $27$. This is also the smallest counterexample: every group of order $p$ and $p^2$ ($p$ prime) is abelian.

Note: the Heisenberg group over $\mathbb{F}_2$ has exponent $4$.

Comment: I thought that mod $2$ it was dihedral.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I don't understand your comment: what do you mean by "it" ?

Comment: @ancientmathematician: you're right, it's not abelian but has exponent $4$, i'll edit.

Comment: It was the Heisenberg group, and thanks @JefLaga